# Getting 500 error when uploading file AWS API using post call in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here I have Image file , I am trying upload file on server through post call , but it is throwing  500 (internal server error). I check my api in postman , over their , In body I selected file ,upload file and got 200 status .
But in my code , it is keep sending 500 error. Here is my code below.
Don't know where I am doing wrong .

HTML

```
 <label class="custom-file-upload">
    <input type="file" id="myImage" accept="image/*" />
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Image Upload
 </label>
```

Javascript

```
$(function(){
        $('#myImage').on('change',function ()
            {
                var filePath = $(this).val();
                console.log(filePath);
                var dataObj = {
                    file:filePath

                };  
                var res = $http.post('fack.url', JSON.stringify(dataObj));
                res.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.message = data;
                });
                res.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    alert( "failure message: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
                });


        });
      })
```

Comment: What is the failure message? Have you checked server logs?

Comment: No server log is not throwing any msg , just saying 500 internal server error

Comment: there is a lot wrong with this code;  firstly, you really shouldn't mix jQuery and Angular; secondly, `$http.success()` is deprecated.  on top of that, it doesn't look like you are actually including the file in the upload.

Comment: Checking your site I notice that none of the services of the api works (login, upload, etc), you must verify the configuration of aws

Comment: also, I'm not sure you can use `json.stringify` on a file object.....

Comment: Let me remove , json.stringify

Comment: not working after removing json.stringify :(

Comment: Can you confirm that your api service is working properly?

Comment: api service is working fine .